# Datepicker works only with an input of double digits

Tags: jquery, html, css, date, datepicker

In my code I have a bootstrap datepicker but it doesn't worki when I set the date as 09/24/2018 however, 9/24/2018 is working.
I want to add a 0 whenever the date figures are single digits.

**In Jquery**

```
          var onlyThisDates = ["09/25/2018", "09/26/2018", "09/29/2018", "09/27/2018", "09/20/2018", "09/21/2018", "09/22/2018", "10/01/2018", "10/03/2018", "10/05/2018", "10/11/2018", "10/15/2018", "10/17/2018"];

          console.log(onlyThisDates);

          $('#doctortime').datepicker({
              format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
              autoclose: true,
              beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                  var dt_ddmmyyyy =(date.getMonth() + 1)  + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                  return (onlyThisDates.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1);
              }
          });
```

**In HTML**

```
<input id="doctortime" class="form-control" placeholder="Doctor Date" name="dates" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

Comment: bootstrap by default doesn't have datepicker. So as you are referencing third party soft you should provide a link so there is no confusion of what you are really referring to. Just because one is more popular doesn't mean there are no other bootstrap datepickers

Comment: also you should mention a version of bootstrap you are using

Comment: You first understand What problem i'm facing and go google bootstrap datepicker you will get ur answer

Comment: I'm not solving your problem I'm suggesting you how to make your question more clear for everyone reading it. As I said I can find multiple results for BS-datepicker. And people using different search engine or from other location where another search result is valued higher might find another project as 1st result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/9vqs2e1L/8/

```
    var onlyThisDates = ["09/20/2018", "09/26/2018", "09/29/2018", "09/27/2018", "09/20/2018", "09/21/2018", "09/22/2018", "10/01/2018", "10/03/2018", "10/05/2018", "10/11/2018", "10/15/2018", "10/17/2018"];         

      $('#doctortime').datepicker({
          format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
          autoclose: true,
           beforeShowDay: function (date) {                              
            var dt_ddmmyyyy = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)  + '/' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();                                     
            return (onlyThisDates.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1);                  
          }
      });
```

Comment: Thank You so much, This is what I was looking for,.. Thanks again

Comment: glad to help you